# Should I select a `Page Layout Version` when using `Custom page content` of Azure AD B2C User flows?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to customize the `Multifactor authentication page` of a B2C User flows. 
If I just modify the layout by adding my CSS & HTML then whether I should select a `Page Layout Version` or not? Because my CSS is based on the css-class or element-id (that is generated by Azure-AD-B2C). So, I'm afraid that those `css-class / element-id` can be changed in the future.

If I don't select the `Page Layout Version`, then whether the MFA behavior may be changed in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `css-class` or `element-id` generated by Azure-AD-B2C will generally not change. If it changes, you also need to change your custom CSS and HTML code, regardless of whether you choose the page layout version.

There are some behaviors changed about MFA page (multifactor) in page layout version 1.1.0. See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout#110).

- 'Confirm Code' button removed
- The input field for the code now only takes input up to six (6)
  characters
- The page will automatically attempt to verify the code entered when a
  6-digit code is entered, without any button having to be clicked
- If the code is wrong, the input field is automatically cleared
- After three (3) attempts with an incorrect code, B2C sends an error
  back to the relying party
- Accessibility fixes
- Default CSS removed

If you don't select 1.1.0, the behaviors will keep on as 1.0.0.

Comment: `If you don't select 1.1.0, the behaviors will keep on as 1.0.0.`
>>Does that mean the B2C will keep using the initial version (1.0.0) if we don't choose any Page layout version even newer versions has been released?

`If it changes, you also need to change your custom CSS and HTML code, regardless of whether you choose the page layout version.`
>>I think the Microsoft should release new version if they have any changes or improvements. So, it will not break any previous versions.

Comment: Yes, If you don't make any choices, b2c will continue to use the original version, if there is a change, the previous version will not be destroyed.

Comment: @TuanVo If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.